# Refresh Datatables with different data

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I try to call the function with a parameter exploited for the kind of ajax call but not working.

```
function contatti(a) {
  if (a === undefined) {
    a = "null";
  }

  $("#contatti").dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bDestroy": true,
      "language": {
        "url": "json/ita.json"
      },
      "ajax": {
        "url": "aj/aj_select_clients.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "data": {
          selezione: a,
          utente_id: utente_id
        }
      },
      "columns": [
         {"data": "nome"},
         {"data": "cognome"},
         {"data": "telefono"},
         {"data": "email"},
         {"data": "citta"}
      ]
    }
  );
}
```

Update function is shown below:

```
function update_contacts(id) {
   $("#contatti").dataTable().fnClearTable();
   $("#contatti").dataTable().fnDestroy();
   contatti(id);
}
```

The result is right count but no data.
  [image: Screenshot]

Comment: when you mention `bDestroy: true` you dont have to do the Destroy manually, so simply comment out those first two lines in `update_contacts` function and see it works or not

Comment: The problem may be in your `aj_select_clients.php` file. Try using a tool like Firebug and watch if it's returning the correct data.